# how to use rest api post correctly with Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have the following service in angular 5 application:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
                'Accept': 'application/json', 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                 })
        };

addTrip(trip: Trip): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Adding trip ' + JSON.stringify(trip));
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/trip/`, JSON.stringify(trip), httpOptions);
  }
```

Trip look like (in angular):

```
export interface Trip {
  description: string;
}
```

The java code is seam component which use rest api:

```
@Name("tripFacadeREST")
@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)
@Path("Trips")
public class TripFacadeREST {

    @In private TripDaoHibernateImpl tripDao;

...

@POST
@Path("Trip")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response addNewTrip(Trip newTrip) {
    tripDao.addTrip(newTrip);
    return Response.ok().entity("trip added successfully").build();
}
```

I can't get this call to work, I have tried also put but I understand that put is for update and because the id is created in the server side I've used post,
the server side is not triggered. Any idea how to solve this problem?
(I was able to use GET annotation in the same service with no issues).

Comment: does your service work using postman?

Comment: I haven't used postman

Comment: You can try postman and fiddler to see if your service works. This way you'll see if your headers are correct etc.. if postman does not work then probably your service is not working. Also it would be helpful to post the response you get from network to help us out.

Comment: I can see in the network tab in the browser that nothing is being sent

Comment: then you should start looking why your web app is not sending the request.

Comment: As mentioned by @steveland83, you should use `subscribe` inorder to get the post is invoked.
`this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(trip), httpOptions).subscribe();`

Comment: @user2304483 I have rolled back your latest edit because that is unrelated to your initial question. Please create a new question if you are unable to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HttpClient code looks ok - and since you arent seeing anything in the network tab I'll bet you arent subscribing to the Observable returned by `addTrip`.

If you dont subscribe to the observable it will not be executed.

*From the docs:*

> Always subscribe!
>
> An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true for all HttpClient methods.

https://angular.io/guide/http#always-subscribe

Comment: I added toPromise call and now I can see the request in the network tab but getting 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Ok, that means that *this* issue is resolved. Please resolve this and open a new question - after trying to fix the new problem yourself first.